# Mixing JSP/HTML any new features or suggestions

Tags: html, jsp, formatting, mixing

I guess my questions are not well described. Is this coding style (like the example below) still recommended?

Aren't there any new methods of mixing html with jsp? I see some examples with the blockquote < script > < /script >. I guess that's for seperating code blockwise and not always the best way.

Any suggestions, let's say a framework, syntax coloring or even formatting would help.

My problem is that the relation or even errors between Class and JSP file is not always displayed well in eclipse. Or it's maybe not easy for a new person to read/understand it.

Here an example

```
<%} %>
<%if(condition) { %>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><%=method()%></td>
    <td class="text"><%=method()%></td>
</tr>
<%} %>
<tr>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking at all.

Comment: I read the question as 'My JSP is a mess due to mixing HTML, JSP and Java. Even Eclipse can't understand it anymore. What can be done?'

Comment: @RoToRa: Maybe because you aren't doing JSP at all?

Comment: @BalusC Only a little, but enough to see that the original question wasn't coherent. But the edit cleared it up and I would have answered along the same line as you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those ugly things are called *scriptlets* and yes, they are considered bad practice since a decade, since the moment that taglibs and EL were born. Nowadays they may be useful for quick prototyping, but really nothing more than that.

Nowadays, you normally use taglibs like [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) to control the page flow and output. You normally use [Expresson Language](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) (EL) to access backend data. You can do fairly a lot at the presentation layer with them. If you comes to a point that it is not possible with either of them and you're forced to grab *scriptlets*, then the code logic ultimately belongs in a *real* Java class. You can use a [`Servlet`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) class to control/preprocess/postprocess requests, you can use a [`Filter`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) class to filter requests, you can use a [`DAO`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) class to do the database interaction, you can use a [`Javabean`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/) class to store/transfer/access data, you can use a `Domain` class for business logic, you can use an `Utility` class for static tools. Use the JSP where it is intented for: a view technology to write template text like HTML/CSS/Javascript in which provides the possibility to interact with backend Java code and data by taglibs and EL.

Those tutorials are very good to get started with them all the right way: [Beginner and Intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html), [Advanced JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/msajsp.html).

That said, the `<script></script>` things where you're talking about have by the way **nothing** to do with Java/JSP. Those are HTML elements which indicate a block of [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). This is an entirely independent language with the first 4 characters of the name and a *less or more* simliar keyword/syntax usage as the *only* relation to Java.

Comment: Thank you BalusC...

This was the appropiate answer for my question.

Comment: Note: I've written a more detailed answer about the subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Answer (score 1):

You could use tag libs (the [Java standard tag lib](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2003/jw-0228-jstl.html?page=1) for instance) if you like. The standard tag libs can help you get those ugly if statements out of the HTML. The statements are there of course, as tags (xml like things), but it fit's better in the JSP, and is easier to work with using Eclipse.

Do be aware that you don't mix business logic and view logic in a JSP. That will *really* make a JSP unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is very similar to:

[JSP - separating Java from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936948/jsp-separating-java-from-html/5195561)