# JSP - separating Java from HTML

Tags: jsp

If I had something like this:

```
<%
    String name =  (String)session.getAttribute("username");

    if(name!=null)
{%>

    <div id="navBar">
            <h2><a href="blah.jsp">Home</a>   |   
        <a href="blah1.jsp">SomewhereElse</a>   |  
    </div>
<%}%>
```

Basically, if variable name is null, don't display navigation bar, but since mixing Java and HTML should be avoided - I can't see how you can rewrite this to separate the 2 languages???

Answer (score 2):

Use taglibs/EL. Your particular example can be solved as follows with help of JSTL [`<c:if>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html):

```
<c:if test="${not empty username}">
    <div id="navBar">
        <h2><a href="blah.jsp">Home</a>   |   
        <a href="blah1.jsp">SomewhereElse</a>   |  
    </div>
</c:if>
```

The given HTML will only be printed when there's no attribute with the name `username` in any of the page, request, session or application scopes.

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [JSTL tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [EL tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a controller (it could be something simple as a plain Java `servlet`). You would send it to different **JSP** pages in one case or the other.

```
// controller
String jsp = "";
boolean userLoggedIn = isUserLoggedId();
if (userLoggedIn) {
   jsp = "logged_in.jsp";
} else {
   jsp = "not_logged_in.jsp";
}
getServletContext().
       getRequestDispatcher(jsp).forward(req, res);
```

**JSP** is not like **PHP** where you "invoke the file" directly. Instead, you should map a URL to a Servlet (controller) and then let that servlet handle internally the JSP part. Do remember to put **JSP** files in `WEB-INF` directory so user won't have direct access to it.

Comment: So if the code I posted was say in home.jsp - you're suggesting that I should create a homeloggedin.html and homeloggedout.html?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with BalusC.

Don't forget to add the following taglib directive:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

This allows you to reference the JSTL core tag library tags

This gives you a lot or useful features like if, choose, foreach, etc

Note that the taglib directive can be added indirectly through another jsp which is included by the current file.

E.g using:

```
<%@ include file="MyJspTagIncludeFile.jsp" %>
```